# How can I turn off deprecation warnings php?

Tags: php

I have been trying to do this for hours. I have looked up every possible solution, tried different BBCode things to parse my BBCode, but I haven't been able to get anything to work. I have just conceded I need to figure out how to turn off deprecation errors. This is the one I am getting as of now:

```
Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; BBCodeLexer has a deprecated constructor in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP Blog/nbbc/nbbc.php on line 67
```

I have tried a few times to change various things, and to add some code to remove deprecation errors. I even added to `php.ini`. Nothing worked. How can I remove deprecation errors in a way that works?

Comment: Are these classes part of your application or part of a library?

Comment: @NigelRen it is a part of NBBC. I have found some alternatives, but couldn't get them to work.

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);` at the beginning of the script. This should turn off the deprecated warnings.